# Cannot use a variable that was returned from a function

Tags: python, function, variables

Code is as follows:

```
def join_files(Fund):
Month_1 = pd.read_excel(Fund[0])
Month_2 = pd.read_excel(Fund[1])
Joined_1 = Month_1[["UNIQUE_ID","NET_AMOUNT"]].merge(Month_2[["UNIQUE_ID","NET_AMOUNT",]], on = "UNIQUE_ID", how = "left")
return Joined_1

join_files(GF)  
print(Joined_1)
```

When I run the code, it gives me an error on the 'print(Joined_1)' line and says that it is an undefined name even though the code above runs successfully.

I know the function works since if I change the return statement to print() the output is printed.

Comment: You didn't store the returned value, do `Joined_1 = join_files(GF)`.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you. Still pretty new and figuring this out as I go.

Comment: Returning a variable doesn't create a variable with the same name in the calling scope. It allows the value that the returned variable held to be used outside of the function. You need to manually assign that value somewhere if you want to store it.

Comment: Please repeat your tutorial materials on functions to see how return and use a value.

Answer (score 0):

That's because your variable of Joined_1 is contained with the join_files() function.  After you return Joined_1, the value of that variable is returned (but not captured).  Then you ask to print the variable, but at that point the script is no longer aware of the Joined_1 variable.  I think you're looking for something more like this.

```
def join_files(Fund):
     ...                // I haven't verified your your excel read logic
     return(Joined_1)

ret_val = join_files(GF)
print(ret_val)
```

You could do a small test with this to get a template started for you:

```
def use_returned_value(some_val)
    new_value = some_val
    return new_value

return_value = use_returned_value(1234)
print(return_value)
```